# In separable metric space every open set is at most countable union of open balls

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(X,\rho)$ be separable metric space. Show that any open set $\emptyset\neq A\subset X$ is at most a countable union of open balls.  Let $X\supset A\neq\emptyset$ be an open set

Let $Y\subset X$ be dense ($\mbox{cl}\,Y = X$) and at most countably infinite. Let's look at 
$$\bigcup_{y\in A\cap Y}B(y,r_y)\overset{?}=A $$

These $r_y>0$ all exist because $A$ is open. Also, $\subset$ is obvious. However:
Let $x\in A$, then there exists $R>0$ s.t $B(x,R)\subset A$ and since $Y$ is dense, there exists $w\in Y\cap A$ s.t $\rho (x,w)<\frac{R}{2} =:r$. At the moment we have $x\in B(w,r)\subset B(x,R)$. For this particular $w$ there exists $r_w>0$ s.t $B(w,r_w)$ is contained in $\bigcup_{y\in A\cap Y}B(y,r_y)$ and this is where I have encountered a problem:
There are two cases to consider.

1. If $r<r_w$, then $r_w-r>0$ and we can "fit" $x$ inside $B(w,r_w)$
2. What do we do when $r_w\leq r$, though? The same "geometric intuition" used in 1. fails here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$B:=\bigcup\{B(y,r)\in\wp(A)\mid y\in Y\wedge r\in\mathbb Q_+\}$$

Then $B$ can be recognized as a countable union of open balls and by definition $B\subseteq A$.

If $x\in A$ then $B(x,R)\subseteq A$ for some $R>0$.

Let $y\in Y$ such that $d(y,x)<\frac{R}2$ and let $r\in\mathbb Q_+$ such that $d(y,x)<r<\frac{R}2$.

Then $x\in B(y,r)\subseteq B(x,R)\subseteq A$.

The first inclusion because for $z\in B(y,r)$ we have: $$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)<\frac{R}2+r<R$$
That justifies the conclusion that $x\in B$ and proved is now that $A=B$.

Comment: a much better way, I think. I encountered a fundamental problem when I defined the union to be arbitrary.

Comment: If $x\in A$ and $x\notin Y$ then every $r_y$ in your question can be chosen in such a way that $x\notin B(y,r_y)$. So your method does not work.